# Unknown column 'parent_var_id' in 'exp_playa_relationships'

Tags: playa, pixelandtonic

I get the following error when updating Playa to V4.4.5

Unknown column 'parent_var_id' in 'exp_playa_relationships'

ALTER TABLE exp_playa_relationships ADD parent_is_draft INT(1) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 AFTER parent_var_id

Filename: third_party/playa/ft.playa.php

Environment is MAMP, EE2.7.0.

This happens when clicking the playa link in the fieldtypes CP display. Oddly, the version is already at 4.4.5 when I do that, but maybe because I ran the module updates before - I was updating two other P&T addons at the same time - Matrix and Assets.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After updating Playa and it failing to run it's update forDB schema, here's what you can try:

Take a look at the columns in exp_playa_relationships table in the database.

- Does it have a field parent_var_id? If no, then the version you should set is 4.1.
- If yes, does it have a field parent_is_draft? If no, then the version you should set is 4.3
- If yes, then the version you should set is 4.4.5

Now, set the version number we determined in the previous three steps for the Playa field in the exp_fieldtypes table and go visit the Add-ons -> Fieldtypes -> Playa page and hit submit.

Everything should be all working now.

Comment: OK - that works, but a weird way to update update no?

Comment: There's a known issue with Playa updates - we'll be taking care of that with the next Playa release. For some people this bug happens, for most people it does not - we haven't been able to pinpoint the exact reason..